# CSS filter that can make colors appear more "rich"?

Tags: css, filter

Someone sent this to me and I'm sure he created in photoshop.

[image]

What I want to do is create a similar red scale colour effect using only HTML CSS.    So what I did was take an image, use CSS to gray-scale it, adjust contrast, and then I put a div with red background and opacity less than 1 on top of the image.  Here's the code and the result.

```css
#container  {
position:relative;
width:450px;
}

img {
width:100%;
display:block;
filter: grayscale(100%) contrast(50%);
}

#overlay {
background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MYn1.jpg" />
<div id="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

I find that no matter what values I adjust for any of the style properties, I can't get the red image to appear as vibrant as the first image at the top.  I tried different shades of red, opacity, contrast, etc..., but my image still appears very "washed out". Are there other CSS properties that can help me make the second image as vibrant as the first image?

Comment: I think you are looking for `background-blend-mode` or `mix-blend-mode`. However the browser support for these properties is poor (no IE). But you can see a demo [here](https://css-tricks.com/basics-css-blend-modes/) and [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/mix-blend-mode/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `mix-blend-mode` for your markup.

```css
#container {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
    position: relative;
    width: 450px;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MYn1.jpg" />
</div>
```

I used a value of `multiply` but you can check out many other values [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/mix-blend-mode/).

Although browser support is limited, you can usually get away with doing your first overlay method for IE users (they don't get cool effects because they don't have a cool browser lol)

There is also `background-blend-mode` if your image is a background image rather than a `<img />`